# How to create boolean method?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a boolean method called isAvailable that accepts a seat number on a flight as a parameter, returns a boolean that indicates whether that seat is available. With code similar to a tic-tac-toe program, the code will convert a seat number like 20 into a row and column index for the two-dimensional array. It returns true if there are *any* available seats on the flight.

```
    public class Flight {

     /*
     * declare instance variables
     * each flight object that is created will have its own copy of these
     * These are declared as private to ensure that external Java code
     * cannot access them directly and assign any arbitrary values to them.
     */
     String flightNumber;
     int rows;
     int seatsPerRow;
     boolean [][] seat;
     double fare;
     String origin;
     String destination;


     /*
     * The constructor
     * Contains code that initially sets up each flight object when it is
     * first created. Always has the same name as the class.
     */
     public Flight (String flightNumber, int rows, int seatsPerRow, double fare,  String origin, String destination) {

    //call the mutator methods and let them initialize the instance variables
    setflightNumber(flightNumber);
    setRows(rows);
    setSeatsPerRow(seatsPerRow);
    setFare(fare);
    setOrigin(origin);
    setDestination(destination);

    seat = new boolean [rows][seatsPerRow]

    for(int i = rows, int x = seatsPerRow; i>0, x>0; i--, x--){
        seat[i][x] = true;
    }
     }//end of constructor


         /*
         * The accessor methods
     * These report the current values of the Flight object's instance variables
     */
     public String getFlightNumber() {
         return flightNumber;
     }

     public int getRows() {
         return rows;
     }

     public int getSeatsPerRow() {
         return seatPerRow;
     }

     public double getFare() {
         return fare;
     }

     public String getOrigin() {
         return origin;
     }

     public String getDestination() {
         return destination;
     }

     public boolean isAvailable(int userRow, int userSeatPerRow) {

    int row = 0;
    int seatPerRow = 0;

     }
}//end of accessors
```

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Question is a bit incomplete. "What do you expect to happen", "what actually happens, with what input / output". All good stuff to help us help you.

Comment: The guy actually wants us to write for him his assignment.

Comment: This is just the class that describes the flight. 
I have created a 2-d boolean array to represent the seats on the flight. each seat is either available or not. seat[0][0] is seat 1, seat[0][1] is seat 2 and so on. So, like if seat[0][0] is true, the seat is available. 

I think I'm having a hard time grasping the concept of determining true or false on which seat. It's just a class file, not the application file, and it's just a method to be called upon by the application file to check if the seat is available or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public boolean isAvailable(int userRow, int userSeatPerRow) {
      return !seat[userRow][userSeatPerRow];
}
```

This assumes that `seat[x][y]` array is true if seat in row x, place y is occupied

if the seat is occupied, then `seat[userRow][userSeatPerRow]` is `true`.

When the `!`, we get the invert the logic, so `true` becomes `false`.

So the function returns `false` is the seat is occupied, since then it is not available. The opposite happens if the seat is empty. Then the function returns `true`

To find the first available seat you would do something like this:

```
 for (int row = 0; row < getRows(); row++) {
     for (int column = 0; column < getSeatsPerRow(); column++) {
         if (isAvailable(row, column)) {
             System.out.println("Sear " + row +", " + column + " is emply!!!!!!");
         }
     } 
 }
```

To check if there are any available seats

```
public boolean areThereAnyAvailableSeats() {
    for (int row = 0; row < getRows(); row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < getSeatsPerRow(); column++) {
            if (!seat[userRow][userSeatPerRow]) {
                return true;
            }
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does that return whether the seat is available or not?
That's what's confusing me. Because I haven't got the user input yet to determine rows and seatsPerRow, those would be the parameters, then I don't understand how to use them to check for true or false?

Comment: Like, would I create a loop to go through each seat or part of the array to check for availability?

Comment: Ok! I understand that! That checks that individual seat (given the parameters to check that spot in the array) for availability!?!

If I were to search for *any* available seats on the flight after that, would I create a loop there?

Comment: OHHH!!! I understand how it's like a tic-tac-toe board now. Can all that be done in the same method? 

Thank you so much, by the way.

Comment: like to print all available seats in a singe method?

Comment: Like, in the application file, when I call this method to check a certain seat for availability, then should I create another method called isAvailable to display if there are *any* seats available or could it work all in the same method?

Comment: Ok! So a separate method to call for each!
This makes more sense now. I understand how it would work when I called these methods from the application class. I made it so much more complicated than it really was. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your function

```
public boolean isAvailable(int userRow, int userSeatPerRow) {

    int row = 0;
    int seatPerRow = 0;

     }
```

does not return anything. Is that because you don't know what to put there, or did you forget...?

Presumably, you will want to have a "book" method that sets a seat to false (toggle a bit in the seat[][] array); the `isAvailable` method needs to access the array and return the value

```
return seat[userRow][userSeatPerRow].
```

Setting `row` and `seatPerRow` to zero in your method, when these are the parameters being passed in, leaves me bewildered.